# How to reset data sort to original sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, plugins

Am working on an existing site where there seems to be a use the DataFilters jQuery Plugin  where data is sorted by lowest price and highest price. For reasons outside my control, I can't edit the original code and there is a requirement to add a link when clicked it will reset the sort to its original state prior to the sort.

Thanks for your help

**UPDATE**: I got access to DataFilter initialisation code similar to what's here: http://www.datafilters.info/config.php

**UPDATE**: I got access to the DataFilter initialisation code which I can update

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#filterControls").show();
    initFilters();
});

function initFilters() {

    function freeTextSearchExtractText(element) {
        return element.find('.brand').text() + " " + element.find('.model').text() + " " + element.find('.stock').text() + " " + element.find('.os').text();
    }

    var sortBy = [
        {"heading": "Price (low-high)", "id": "cost", "direction": "1"},
        {"heading": "Price (high-low)", "id": "cost", "direction": "-1"},
        {"heading": "Brand (A-Z)", "id": "brand", "direction": "1"},
        {"heading": "Brand (Z-A)", "id": "brand", "direction": "-1"}
    ]

    $('#handsetList').DataFilter('init', {
        "filters": [
            {"id":"cost", "dataType":"currency", "filterType":"sortOnly"},

            {"heading": "Brand", "id": "brand", "dataType": "default", "filterType": "checkboxes" },
            {"heading": "4G readiness",   "id": "tariffType", "dataType": "default",  "filterType": "checkboxes", "hideSingleItem": "true" },
            {"heading": "Refurbished", "id": "model", "dataType": "default", "filterType": "checkboxes", "items": ["~Refurb"] },
            {"heading": "Stock status", "id": "stock", "dataType": "stock", "filterType": "checkboxes" },

            {"heading": "Operating system", "id": "os", "dataType": "default", "filterType": "checkboxes"}
        ],

        "pageSize": 9,
        "useFreeTextSearch": true,
        "freeTextSearchHeading": "Search phones",
        "freeTextSearchExtractTextFn": freeTextSearchExtractText,
        "sortingDropDown": sortBy,
        "sortingDropDownHeading": "Sort phones",
        "onSuccess": onSuccessFnDesktop,
        "useLoadingOverlayOnFilterIfSlow": true,
        "slowTimeMs": 300,
        "hashNavigationEnabled": true
    });

    var checkVisible = setInterval(function() {
        if($('.filterWrapper').length == 0 || !$('.filterWrapper').is(':visible')) return;
        clearInterval(checkVisible);
        merchandisedFilters();
    }, 300);
}
```

Comment: If you cannot edit the code, you only can link to reload the page. It would be hard anyway because likely the original order is stored nowhere

Comment: Page reload is one option but would like to avoid if possible. Storing original sort I would like to explore further if that's an option.

Comment: I got access to DataFilter initialisation code similar to what's here: http://www.datafilters.info/config.php

Comment: Then show us the existing code, and link the docs of the exact plugin you're using.

Comment: @Bergi Question updated with link to plugin and code.